# Laravel 4 ODBC class cannot find php extension

Tags: php, pdo, laravel, odbc, composer-php

I'm trying to install the odbc class for laravel from https://github.com/ccovey/odbc-driver

Here is my composer.json snipped:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",       
    "ccovey/odbc-driver-l4": "1.1.*"    
},
```

When i run "composer update" i get the following:

```
ccovey/odbc-driver-l4 v1.1.1 requires ext-pdo-odbc * -> the requested 
PHP extension pdo-odbc is missing from your system.
```

I already commented the pdo odbc extension in php.ini in xampp\php

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

To be sure, running "php -m", here is the output (reduced for space):

```
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv
Phar
```

PDO_ODBC is loaded!

I ran "composer show -p":

```
ext-pcre            0          The pcre PHP extension
ext-PDO             1.0.4dev   The PDO PHP extension
ext-pdo_mysql       1.0.2      The pdo_mysql PHP extension
ext-PDO_ODBC        1.0.1      The PDO_ODBC PHP extension
ext-pdo_sqlite      1.0.1      The pdo_sqlite PHP extension
ext-pdo_sqlsrv      3.0.3421.0 The pdo_sqlsrv PHP extension
```

ext-PDO_ODBC is loaded!

However when i ran "composer show -p ext-pdo_odbc":

```
name     : ext-PDO_ODBC
descrip. : The PDO_ODBC PHP extension
keywords :
versions : * 1.0.1
type     : library
license  :
source   : []
dist     : []
names    : ext-pdo_odbc
```

so composer can see ext-pdo_odbc successfully.

i'm using xampp 1.8.2 [PHP: 5.4.19]

Why is the package throwing an error requiring "ext-pdo-odbc" while the extension name is "ext-pdo_odbc" ?

Comment: The instance of PHP in your command line may not be the same that's running on your webserver, especially if using WAMP or XAMPP.  Use `phpinfo()` instead and be sure you have restarted your web services as well.

Comment: Composer is looking for that package because you just told it to.  You should be using `composer show -p ext-pdo_odbc`

Comment: yes, composer can find ext-pdo_odbc, but the error message shows it's looking for ext-pdo-odbc

Comment: Because you typed in `composer show -p ext-pdo-odbc`

Comment: to clarify: the package is requiring "ext-pdo-odbc (with a dash), while the name of the extension is "ext-pdo_odbc" (with an underscore). Why is the package requesting the wrong extension name ?